# Can I remove the "pause" button from vscode debugger toolbar?

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am writing a debug adapter for vscode.

Unfortunately, our debugger does not have pause functionality. Because of that, I would like to remove/disable the pause button/command (workbench.action.debug.pause) from vscode debugger. Is this possible?

For now, I am overriding "pauseRequest" and displaying a message to the user saying that this feature is not supported.

I would prefer if I could remove the "pause" button from the toolbar in the first place.